If you want a view to force to width fill on its superview, is it actually as simple as setting intrinsic to .greatestFiniteMagnitude?
Say you have, for example, a vertical stack view. Its alignment is leading (because you want most items to shrink left).
However you have one special type of item you want to be full width.
I have always done some sort of complicated solution to achieve this:
class FullWidthThing: .. {
    
    ..
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
    private lazy var fullWidth: NSLayoutConstraint = {
        guard let sv = superview else { return NSLayoutConstraint() }
        let v = widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sv.widthAnchor)
        v.isActive = true
        return v
    }()
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        if superview != nil {
            _ = fullWidth
        }
        super.layoutSubviews()
    }
}

But is it actually just as simple as setting the intrinsic with to .greatestFiniteMagnitude? Superficial testing shows this seems to work:
private lazy var setup: () = {
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
    ...
    return ()
}()

override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    var sz = super.intrinsicContentSize
    sz.width = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
    return sz
}

Should this work, or is there a problem with doing this, or is there a common way of doing this?

For any view, Auto-layout -- whether in a stack view or other hierarchy -- will use the .intrinsicContentSize unless something else affects the size. So, yes, if you want a view to be as wide as the available width, that will work.

For any view, Auto-layout -- whether in a stack view or other hierarchy -- will use the .intrinsicContentSize unless something else affects the size.
Consider this layout:

The Yellow frame is a Vertical Stack View, with Top and Leading constraints, spacing: 12 and alignment: Leading
Each outline frame is also a vertical stack view, distribution: fill equally, spacing: 4 and alignment: Leading, containing a label and a (default) UIView.
We cannot see the views, because they have no width.
Each "sub" stack view has a width matching the intrinsic width of its label, and the outer stack view has a width of the widest "sub" stack view.
Outer Stack width: 300.0 (intrinsic width of widest label)

Now, let's add another sub-stack view with a label that is too wide to fit the screen:

Outer Stack width: 833.6666666666666

Next, let's add a Trailing constraint to the outer stack view:

Outer Stack width: 353.0

and, with the longer 4th string:

Outer Stack width: 353.0 (still)

So, what happens if, instead of a default UIView we use a subclassed "wide" view:
class WideView: UIView {
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        var sz = super.intrinsicContentSize
        sz.width = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
        return sz
    }
}

The value of .greatesFiniteMagnitude is 1.7976931348623157e+308 ... if we format that as a float ("%0.0f") we get a number that is 309 digits long.
Here's what we get with the first 3 strings, NO Trailing anchor on the outer stack view:

Outer Stack width: 2777777.0 (greatest width allowed by UIKit)

If we add the longer string:

It looks the same, and again:
Outer Stack width: 2777777.0 

Add the outer stack view Trailing anchor:

Outer Stack width: 353.0


Here's the class I used to generate those outputs (see the comments and commented lines):
class WideTestVC: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        
        let strs: [String] = [
            "Short",
            "Medium length",
            "Longer string for width testing",
            //"This string will be too long to fit the available width of a phone in portrait orientation!",
        ]
        let colors: [UIColor] = [
            .systemRed,
            .systemGreen,
            .systemBlue,
            .cyan,
        ]
        
        let outerStack = UIStackView()
        outerStack.axis = .vertical
        outerStack.alignment = .leading
        outerStack.spacing = 12
        
        for (str, c) in zip(strs, colors) {
            let st = UIStackView()
            st.axis = .vertical
            st.alignment = .leading
            st.distribution = .fillEqually
            st.spacing = 4
            st.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
            st.layer.borderWidth = 1
            
            let label = UILabel()
            label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 24.0, weight: .light)
            label.text = str
            label.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
            
            // to see the difference...
            // use standard UIView (will have no width)
            let v = UIView()
            // or, use custom "WideView" with width: .greatestFiniteMagnitude
            //let v = WideView()
            
            v.backgroundColor = c
            st.addArrangedSubview(label)
            st.addArrangedSubview(v)
            outerStack.addArrangedSubview(st)
        }
        
        outerStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(outerStack)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        // constrain ONLY Top / Leading, or
        // constrain Top / Leading / Trailing
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            outerStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 30.0),
            outerStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            //outerStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
        ])
        
        outerStack.backgroundColor = .yellow
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let v = view.subviews.first as? UIStackView
        else { return }
        
        print(v.frame.width)
        
    }
}


Amazing!  If I read the logic right, the conclusion is that the layout engine uses . greatesFiniteMagnitude as "as long as possible, but, limited by any other solutions that result in  a certain width."

@Fattie - or, more precisely and generic: the layout engine uses the view's .intrinsicContentSize whenever needed, but that will be ignored if any other solutions result in a certain height or width"

Right .. perhaps it is "limited by"?   Hence, containing vert stack has a fixed width of 1000 and is .leading.  You put in it a hori stack which contains only a label of string width 200. The hori stack has an intrinsic width of 200 (as does the label).  It is drawn as 200.  the intrinisic width is not ignored per se, it's the width. (I guess that's how to look at it?)  You now override the intrinsic width of the inner stack to be 1100.  The 1100 is indeed now ignored and it is forced to 1000.

@Fattie - say the intrinsic width is 250.0 ... if your constraints (or the stack view) tell it to be 200.0, it will be 200.0 -- f your constraints (or the stack view) tell it to be 300.0, it will be 300.0. So, if the intrinsic width is .greatestFiniteMagnitude, sure, you could say "limited" ... but that is a little misleading in more generic auto-layout / intrinsic size terms.

Ah I really see what you're saying.  Indeed it is always "limited" in that sense (ie as in the example in the first sentence in your comment just there). Good one!
